# recommended naming convention for cffi/foreign types

Tags: common-lisp, ccl, cffi

In common lisp, is there a *recommended* naming convention for foreign types? (and types in general)?  For example:

```common-lisp
(cffi:defctype glyph-index-t :uint32)
(cffi:defcstruct Point
    (x :int32)
    (y :int32))

(cffi:define-foreign-library fontlib (t (:default "font")))
(cffi:use-foreign-library fontlib)

(cffi:defctype font-ptr-t :pointer)
(cffi:defcfun "hasKerning" :boolean (fontptr font-ptr-t))
(cffi:defcfun "getKerning" Point 
     (fontptr font-ptr-t) 
     (glyph1 glyph-index-t) 
     (glyph2 glyph-index-t))
```

In this example `defcstruct Point` corresponds to C/C++ type `struct Point{int32 x, y;};`, `glyph-index-t` corresponds to `typedef uint32 GlyphIndex;` and `font-ptr-t` is `struct Font*`.

I'm unsure whether I should simply add `-t` suffix to everything (as I did with `glyph-index-t`), make the interpreter case-sensitive (so I could use Uppercase to indicate types, like in C++, which is probably a bad idea), or whether there is some other traditional way to do it.  Any advice?

Comment: Just a nitpick—the interpreter (and compiler) are always case sensitive;  it's the _reader_ that does upcasing by default.  You can still used mixed-case symbol names with the default readtable by escaping accordingly, e.g., `|MixedCaseSymbol|` or `us\o\fa`.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor: Yeah, I know that, but AFAIK, case-sensitive lisp is a very non-standard/"unusual" coding style. On other hand, I'm programming for myself, so this shouldn't be a problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some testing, I found out that cffi typenames don't collide with CLOS classes and defstructs. So distinct type name is not necessary.

Regarding "standard for type names" in general, lisp has separate "namespaces" for functions and  types. (to be precise, same symbol can be used as function name and as a type name, as far as I can tell).

Conclusion: It looks like distinct naming scheme for cffi types is unnecessary.

Comment: Was there a question about the namespaces?  Naming conventions can be used to avoid collisions, but that's hardly their only purpose.  When working with foreign libraries, naming conventions are at least as important for translation issues (e.g., being able to reliably convert between `NtCreateThread` and `nt-create-thread`, or between `isSerializable` and `serializable-p`) as they are for namespace collisions.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor: I was talking about *type* names, not function names. As far as I can tell `(defctype`'d type doesn't clash with lisp types(`defstruct`/`defclass`), at all. From what I can tell, there's some kind of hidden internal mechanism that uses those cffi typenames as symbols, and that's it - they don't even seem to be lisp types. The reason why I asked is because other languages I know don't work this way - they need unique identifiers for everything. So am I missing something?

Comment: You're not missing anything;  they're conceptually different namespaces.  CL makes this easy; you could use a hidden table, or just add something to the [symbol's plist](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_symb_4.htm).  The confusion on my part was that the question didn't mention anything about naming _to avoid namespace collision_.  Naming conventions can do more than simulate namespaces, they help programmers (and the environment) find and recognize names.  E.g,. in Scheme, predicates end in `?`;  in Common Lisp they in `p` or `-p`.  `defstruct` uses this to automatically _generate_ predicate names.

Comment: Similarly, the libraries that do foreign interfacing can use naming conventions to help find or generate the corresponding foreign names.    For instance, one could automatically translate `nt-create-thread` to `NtCreateThread` based on the naming convention, and the convention (in that case) wouldn't have anything to do with namespace collision avoidance.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor: "The confusion on my part was that the question didn't mention anything about naming to avoid namespace collision". I don't think I asked the question because I wanted to avoid collisions (unsure). You see, I'm used to C++ thinking (anything is identifier, and they can clash), and when I asked the question I forgot that lisp treats types differently (they don't clash with functions), and that you can work with "symbols". So I kinda assumed that cffi declares lisp type, and there's a need to avoid clashes, which turned out to be untrue. (continued...)

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor: Another reason why I asked is that in C++, in order to avoid identifier clashes, there are different naming conventions. Hungarian notation, CamelCase ("Variable" is a type "variable" is a variable/method), MFC style("CPoint", "TPoint") and so on. So I wanted to know whether there's standard naming conention - like this - in lisp. So I don't think "avoiding collisions" is the main thing I was interested in when I asked. ... Did that explain (intent behind) my original question?

Answer (score 2):

CFFI has a [number of functions](http://common-lisp.net/project/cffi/manual/html_node/Functions.html#Functions) relating to the translation of names.  That linked documentation includes:

- [translate-camelcase-name](http://common-lisp.net/project/cffi/manual/html_node/translate_002dcamelcase_002dname.html#translate_002dcamelcase_002dname)
- [translate-name-from-foreign](http://common-lisp.net/project/cffi/manual/html_node/translate_002dname_002dfrom_002dforeign.html#translate_002dname_002dfrom_002dforeign)
- [translate-name-to-foreign](http://common-lisp.net/project/cffi/manual/html_node/translate_002dname_002dto_002dforeign.html#translate_002dname_002dto_002dforeign)
- [translate-underscore-separated-name](http://common-lisp.net/project/cffi/manual/html_node/translate_002dunderscore_002dseparated_002dname.html#translate_002dunderscore_002dseparated_002dname)

It probably make sense to try to use names that interact well with these functions.  For instance, there's an example on the `translate-name-from-foreign` page (which I realize is about function naming, not type naming, though):

```
CFFI> (defcfun "someXmlFunction" ...)
=> SOME-XML-FUNCTION
```

I'd also suggest finding some libraries that use CFFI to generate bindings, and looking at what they do.